# How to suppress antialiasing of an image in shiny?

Tags: css, r, image, shiny, antialiasing

I have an `image` graphics in a **shiny** app with a relative large number of grid cells. However, smooth color transitions appear distorted in the browser. I suspect that this is an antialiasing artifact and wonder how it can be prevented, either in R or with a css option.

Here a minimal example in plain R, that looks smooth as expected:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
mycol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))

png("image.png", width=600, height=600)
x <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length.out = 200)
r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, x^2, `+`))
image(z = cos(r^2) * exp(-r/6), col = mycol(100))
dev.off()
```

[image: picture with smooth colors]

And the corresponding **shiny** demo, where the resulting image shows an annoying grid artifact:

```
library(shiny)
library(RColorBrewer)

mycol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotOutput("imagePlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$imagePlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length.out = 200)
        r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, x^2, `+`))
        image(z = cos(r^2) * exp(-r/6), col = mycol(100))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: image with distorted colors]

Comment: I know [`renderPlot`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/1.7.4/renderplot) supports the `res=` argument, but in quick playing, it does not do well for me. This question might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/51409188/3358272.

Comment: I tried `res=` already, but it did not help. The surprising thing is, that temporary images of my full application are stored in full resolution in the temporary `tempdir()` folder, so I suspect that antialiasing of the the browser can be the reason and there may be possibilities to switch this off. I will of course try the other method, mentioned.

Comment: The [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51409188/3358272) solves indeed the problem with the artifacts, by using `renderImage` instead of `renderPlot`. The price is, however, that the size of the images must be given in fixed pixels, so it does not adapt to the browser. I still hope, that there are alternatives.

Comment: Good question and nice minimal reproducible example: +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very better with the parameter `useRaster = TRUE`:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$imagePlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length.out = 200)
    r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, x^2, `+`))
    image(z = cos(r^2) * exp(-r/6), col = mycol(100), useRaster = TRUE)
  })
}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer solves the question for the given example. I had tried `useRaster = TRUE` already for my original problem, where it did not help. However, the original app calls `image` indirectly via another package. After tracking things down, it seems to be a bug in that package. Good that R is OpenSource.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Good point. Post an answer if you find.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I saw you can also use a number for `useRaster`. Don't know whether this helps. Otherwise I would use `rasterImage` instead of `image`.

Comment: My "real" application is a little bit more complex, using `plot3D::image2D` that then calls `image`. It supports `rasterImage` in principle, but there seems to be a bug, because it does not change something. I'll try to spot it, or create my own function.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I've read somewhere that rasters have potential problems on Windows. But isn't it poissble (but painful) to color the grid lines?

Comment: `useRaster = TRUE` works now also for the "real" application. The trick was to change the data type at the x axis from POSIX to float.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `renderImage/imageOutput` which scales with the window size. Is it appropriate for your real application?

```r
library(shiny)
library(RColorBrewer)

mycol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))

ui <- fluidPage(
  imageOutput("image")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$image <- renderImage({
    
    # Get width and height of image output
    width  <- session$clientData$output_image_width
    height <- session$clientData$output_image_height
    
    myimage <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    png(myimage, width = width, height = height)
    x <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length.out = 200)
    r <- sqrt(outer(x^2, x^2, `+`))
    image(z = cos(r^2) * exp(-r/6), col = mycol(100))
    dev.off()
    
    # info list
    list(
      src = myimage,
      contentType = "image/png",
      width = width,
      height = height,
      alt = "This is alternate text"
    )
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```